# Play sound depending on command return status

Tags: linux, command-line, audio

Is there an utility which takes a command as argument, runs it and plays sound (or just beeps) depending on the return status? "Good" beep if it's success and "bad" beep if it's failure.

So I can run compiler and take a nap while it builds. And if it will be successful sound, I won't worry.

The question is asked in funny manner, but I really need this tool. I'll have to write my own if there isn't one existing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
./my_compile_command; if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then mpg123 "VanHalen_1984_02_Jump.mp3"; else mpg123 "SpiceGirls_Spice_1_Wannabe.mp3"; fi
```

Something like that should work. Of course you will need mpg123 working.

Comment: I should point out that this assumes that your compiler exits with a status of 0 when it is successful.

Comment: Thanks Kirk, that's is what I need. My compiler does this thing.

Comment: @Peth absolutely correct. Old habits die hard as they say.

Comment: But `$?` is useful thing. I do `exit $?` in my script to simulate behavior of the original program.